# How to detect all divs display style in javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, display

Lets say i have 5 divs,

Div1 to div5.

They all have different display style,

sometimes 2 are none,

sometimes 2 are block.

sometimes all are none,

Sometimes all are block.

Due to the functions i set.

And i want to make a if statement that happens
when all divs are style. Display= block.

Something like

If (all divs are style. Display. = block ) { something }

But i dont know how to use && for 5 divs in JavaScript if statement.

Please guide me further.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.every` after converting querySelectorAll into an array:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
if (Array.from(divs).every((el)=> el.style.display == "block") {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

So, you want to find the first element that isn't `block`. If none, exist undefined would be returned which means all are `block`.

```js
const allAreBlock = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div")).find(
  (div) => getComputedStyle(div).display !== "block"
)

document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = !allAreBlock
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div style="display: none"></div>

Are all elements block?: <span id="status"></span>
```